# Magento products have suddenly stopped appearing in New Products and Search

Tags: magento, product, searchbar

We've recently noticed that only the items in the root folder of a category will show up in the New Products block on the homepage and as results via the Search Box.

I've tried flushing the cache, re-indexing the tables and I've double checked that my date ranges are correct and all items are in stock etc.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You are talking about the default New Products Block and other products have `new_from_date` and `new_to_date` set properly so today is within the daterange?

Comment: I've tried that - it seems to ignore the daterange data and will only display products that are in the root folder.

The only things we've been doing recently to the site are editing the styles.css file and flushing the cache on occasion when editing the footer files.

Comment: You are sure it is the default New Product Block and not just a category block? Was it inserted in CMS or in a layout file? Please show the corresponding code.

Comment: Indeed sir, to be fair it was working for years and then all of a sudden it stopped working and the same products that won't appear in New Products, won't appear in Search either.

Image link:
http://i6.photobucket.com/albums/y239/Ranasaur/cat_fail_zpsb698336a.jpg

Comment: Ok, convinced:) There are no exceptions in log I guess, so I can't help you for now.

Comment: Can anybody else please help with this?

Comment: Comments don't bump your question.
From stackoverflow.com/faq:

Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.

Comment: I found a workaround but don't know how to edit my original question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here's the solution.

It's as simple as disabling the required products and then re-enabling them.

TIP: If doing this in bulk, do NOT do 200 products at a time as it will freeze and you may be locked out of admin. I had a hair raising few minutes by doing that. I restarted my machine and then all was well again.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Self answering your question was a better way than editing it.

Comment: Thank you sir. I'm still a noob learning my way around here so I appreciate your patience.